# combining 3 functors into 1

Tags: c++, functor

I have 3 functors and was wondering if these can be combined into 1, perhaps as a template.
is it possible? if so, how would I do it. thx!

```
    struct less_than
    {
    bool operator()(double prev,double curr) const
    {
    return prev<curr;
    }
    };

    struct great_than
    {
    bool operator()(double prev,double curr) const
    {
    return prev>curr;
    }
    };

    struct equal_to
    {
    bool operator()(double prev, double curr) const
    {
    return prev==curr;
    }
    };
```

Comment: You're likely to get more answers if you actually tag with the language you're talking about, instead of using a single tag with 1 follower.

Comment: thanks Wooble, I shall fix that

Comment: what the hell is the point of combining the less than, and greater than operator??

Comment: As you're new here, make sure to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote features.

Comment: ok, I have to figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, specialized by the operator, then the answer is, **no, not at the language level**.

Luckily, the STL already provides functors for this ([`std::equal_to`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/equal_to/), etc.).  You can either use these directly, or use them as arguments to your own function classes.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. thx Oli, I will check out the STL functors. I don't need to rewrite if it already exists :-)

Comment: shouldn't this work?

struct compare:public binary_function<double, double, bool>
{  
bool operator()(const double curr, const double prev) const
{
if (curr>prev)
  { return 1;}
else
  {
if(curr<prev){ return -1;}
  else
{return 0;}
  }
}
};

but it is returning 1 when curr is less than prev, while working correctly for greater than and equal to..where's my error?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class Functors
{
private:
bool f1(double, double)
{
}

bool f2(double, double)
{
}
bool f3(double, double)
{
}
public:
bool test(int op, double a, double b)
{
//better use function selector, this is only simple example
 if (op == 1)
  return f1(a, b);
 if (op == 2)
  return f2(a, b);
 if (op == 3)
  return f3(a, b);
}
};
```

use it:

```
vector<double> v;
int op = select_op();
//sort vector
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), boost::bind(&Functors::test, Functors(), op, _1, _2));
```

Answer (score 0):

As these are all existent in the standard library, you can just do

```
template<class F>
struct compare
{
    compare(F _f)
        : f(_f) {};
    bool operator()(double prev, double curr) const
    {
        return f(prev, curr);
    }
    F f;
};
```

And use e.g. `compare< std::less<double> >`. But this would be quite useless, as you can just use the standard library functors directly.

Comment: thx Christian, I guess I'll use the std library functors directly

Comment: @itcplpl You can only accept one, but you can at least up-vote other good answers.

Comment: it says I need a 15 reputation to up-vote???? I am only at 10 ;-(...I am trying the greater_equal STL, maybe I will ask another q? on that and get it up to 15 ;-)

Comment: @itcplpl Ah, didn't remember there's a rep-limit for up-voting, then it's no problem.

Comment: can you help me figure out the error on this greater_equal:`code`   #include <iostream>#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct greater_equal:public binary_function<double, double, bool>
{
  bool operator()(double x, double y) const
  {
    return x>=y;}
};

int main()
{
  double prev;
  double curr;
  cout<<"enter 1st num: ";
  cin>>prev;
  cout<<"enter 2nd num: ";
  cin>>curr;
  cout<<"\n";
  double result=greater_equal<double>(curr,prev);
  if (result)
    cout<<"curr greater than prev";
  else
    cout<<"curr less than prev";
  return 0;
}`code`